# php testing on gitlab ci composer

Tags: php, testing, build, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm tryning to do some basic static analysis with my little php code.
I want to use:
phploc
phpcpd
phpcs

my project folder structure is as follows:

```
    .
    |-- ci
    |   `-- docker_install.sh
    |-- css
    |   `-- css.css
    |-- index.php
    |-- js
    |   |-- icons.json
    |   `-- script.js
    `-- process.php
```

I created shell script docker_install.sh with the following code:

```
# Install git (the php image doesn't have it) and other tools
apt-get update -yqq
apt-get install git phploc phpcpd phpmd php-pear -yqq

#install composer
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

and my build file:

```
  image: php:7.0
  before_script:
    #insatll needed packeges
    - bash ci/docker_install.sh > /dev/null
  test:app:
    script:
      #Static analysis
      - phploc .
      #phpmd check coding style
      - phpmd . text naming
      #checking Coding Standards with PHP Code Sniffer
      - phpcpd .
      #Viewing Coding Standards Violations
      - phpcs --standard=PEAR --report=summaryy
```

The build file with the following error:

```
  ....
  $ phpcpd .

  Warning: require_once(Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ClassLoader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /usr/share/php/SebastianBergmann/PHPCPD/autoload.php on line 2

  Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ClassLoader.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /usr/share/php/SebastianBergmann/PHPCPD/autoload.php on line 2
  ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1
```

My questions:
How to enhance this, and how to make it works ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You've installed composer but you never run `composer install`. Just add it to the end of your docker_install.sh file.

Comment: Thanks @Jakub Kania, but now it fails with following error:
 
    ... 
     + mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
     + composer install
    Do not run Composer as root/super user! See   https://getcomposer.org/root for details
    Composer could not find a composer.json file in /builds/test
    To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
    ERROR: Build failed: exit code 1